# How would I prove this limit?

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Prove using the definition of a limit that $$\lim_\limits{x\to0}\sin(x)=0. $$
And $$\lim_\limits{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1.$$

I need to prove that $\forall\epsilon>0 \,\,\exists  \delta >0$ that $$\left|\frac{\sin(x)}{x}-1\right|<\epsilon\quad \text{whenever} \quad |x|<\delta.$$

So 
$$\left|\frac{\sin(x)}{x}-1\right|=\left|\frac{\sin(x)-x}{x}\right|< \frac{1+|x|}{|x|}=\frac1{|x|}+1<\epsilon $$
So in this case would my $\delta $ be $1/(\epsilon-1)$? But then this would be true for $|x|>\delta$, and it might be negative, so how should I do this?

And for the first:
$$|\sin(x)|<1<\epsilon$$
But how would this help me? Since I need it in the form $|x|<f(\epsilon)$ where $f$ is any expression of $\epsilon$.

—-

I know that $\sin(x)$ behaves like $x$ for values close to $0$ but using this argument for the proofs above seems kind of circular.

Also, I am familiar with the geometric proof for the second limit, but I wanted to know how an epsilon-delta proof might look like if I did not have any knowledge of such proof. I should mention that methods more advanced than taking a limit (ex: Taylor series) should not be used.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/75130/75923) might help.

Comment: use the Taylor theorem

Comment: @drhab I am familiar with the geometric proof, I was looking for something that did not need to have such knowledge

Comment: @Masacroso I am guessing that in this case it is assumed to not use methods more advanced than limits.

Comment: @user372003 I can see only two approach: a geometrical proof or an analytical proof (using Taylor of analytic definition of sine analytic definition)

Comment: You want to avoid using that $1$ is an upper bound for $\sin$ here, since an important part of this convergence is that $\sin$ and $x$ are both going to $0$. Squeeze theorem might be a good method here.

Comment: @AlexanderJ93 Squeeze theorem? How would that be a good method? I mean it is easy to apply it to the case where $x$ is approaching infinity, but I can’t see how it would make things simpler for this case.

Comment: If you can show that, within a certain range of $0$, that $\cos(x) \leq \sin(x)/x \leq 1$, then you should have it. Showing that $\cos(x) \rightarrow 1$ as $x \rightarrow 0$ is a much simpler limit.

Comment: The essential question here is the following: What is your definition of $\sin$?